# D3: how to draw dots on line graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, anomaly-detection

i'm developing an anomaly graph in which there will be a line graph on top of that i need to g=draw an dots and show the anomaly as dots

as of now i was able to draw line graph my full code

how to draw dots?? i have anomaly value with the same value which was used to create line graph

all data:

```
[
  {date:14/01/1990,value:23}, 
  {date:15/01/1990,value:24},  
  {date:16/01/1990,value:28},  
  {date:17/01/1990,value:30} 
]
```

anomaly data:

```
[
   {date:14/01/1990,value:23}, 
   {date:17/01/1990,value:30},
]
```

Here is my code:

```
 var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

    var x = d3.scaleTime()
        .rangeRound([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .rangeRound([height, 0]);



    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) {
                return x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) {
                return y(d.close); });
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
               y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

               g.append("g")
                   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                   .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
                 .select(".domain")
                   .remove();
               g.append("g")
                   .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
                 .append("text")
                   .attr("fill", "#000")
                   .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                   .attr("y", 6)
                   .attr("dy", "0.71em")
                   .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                   .text("xxx ($)");

               g.append("path")
                   .datum(data)
                   .attr("fill", "none")
                   .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
                   .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
                   .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
                   .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
                   .attr("d", line);
```

Comment: Does your code actually work? There are few things wrong like `parseTime` being the incorrect format to the date you use.

Comment: @Harpal what should be the actual format